# Spring RabbitMQ Integration, Client ID, User Id & App Id to identify unique client

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

In my application, i would like to track which user/client/app is connected/disconnected to RabbitMQ broker.

For client connection, How do i set unique ID so that i shall be able to find which client (both producer/consumer) is connected or not.

By the way i am using Spring Integration to deal with RabbitMQ/AMQP.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#connections).

> Starting with version 1.7, a `ConnectionNameStrategy` is provided for the injection into the `AbstractionConnectionFactory`. The generated name is used for the application-specific identification of the target RabbitMQ connection. The connection name is displayed in the management UI if RabbitMQ server supports it. This value doesn’t have to be unique and cannot be used as a connection identifier e.g. in HTTP API requests. This value is supposed to be human-readable and is a part of `ClientProperties` under `connection_name`.Can be used as a simple Lambda:

```
connectionFactory.setConnectionNameStrategy(connectionFactory -> "Connection from " + appName);
```

Since 1.4.5, you can also name consumers by adding a `ConsumerTagStrategy` to the listener container.

See [Consumer Tags](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#consumerTags).